# Retrieve a list of events for a specific message

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I know that I can setup a webhook, then as soon the event happens (user open email, spam, etc) SendGrid will call that webhook. but if for some space of time the webhook is down, how to retrieve events for example for an specific sg_message_id?

I have looked at the documents but I can't find a sample call to do this

Answer (score 2):

SendGrid doesn't have message-level API GET, just the Push-based Webhook. You can review the Activity page for short-term event lists.